# Sorting NSMutableArray objects according to the epoch time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have NSMutableArray which contains NSObjects. Each NSObject contains a NSString as property which has epoch time. Now i want to sort the array objects according to epoch time...please help me to achieve this...Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you storing the time values in your NSObject subclass? Also, possible duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348748/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-of-managed-objects-through-an-object-graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting an array is easy. All you need is a piece of code that can compare two objects in the array. You can provide that code in the form of a method, function, or comparator block. So, let's say you opt for the comparator:

```
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^(NSString *string1, NSString *string2) {
        // your code goes here
    }];
```

Replace the commented line with your code to get the times from each string and compare them. This is likely the part you're really asking about. I can't provide that code for you since I don't know exactly what your strings look like. If the only thing in the string is the number of seconds since the epoch, then it's as simple as calling NSString's `-longLongValue` method:

```
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^(NSString *string1, NSString *string2) {
        long long time1 = [string1 longLongValue];
        long long time2 = [string2 longLongValue];
        NSComparisonResult result = NSOrderedDescending;
        if (time1 < time2)
            result = NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (time1 == time2)
            result = NSOrderedSame;
        return result;
    }];
```

If your strings contain other information, you may need to use some NSString methods or a NSScanner to extract the information you want. To keep your comparator block simple, you might want to use a category to add an `-epochTimeValue` method that extracts the time to NSString. That'd let you use code similar to what's above.

Answer (score -1):

Hi please sort in this way.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"YOURSTRINGKEY" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName];
NSArray *sortedArray = [YOUR_ARRAY sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

THIS WILL WORK FOR YOU