# How to sort NSMutableArray by object's pararameter

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I've got `NSMutableArray` with objects `Link` which has parameter `Byte taskOne`. I have to sort objects by this parameter.

```
    for (Byte i = 0; i < [linksArray count]-1; i++) {
        Link *l = [linksArray objectAtIndex:i];
        Link *lNext = [linksArray objectAtIndex:i+1];
        if (l.taskOne >= lNext.taskOne) {
            NSLog(@"%d >= %d", l.taskOne, lNext.taskOne);
            [linksArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:lNext];
            [linksArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i+1 withObject:l];
        }
    }
```

this give me wrong results, but i don't know what's wrong. 
thank you for help.

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348748/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-of-managed-objects-through-an-object-graph) link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to sort an array is to use `NSSortDescriptor` with KVC, like this:

```
NSArray *linksArray;    // Assume that this contains objects which respond to the -taskOne method

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"taskOne" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedLinks = [linksArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

This will create a new array. To sort an `NSMutableArray` in place, do this:

```
NSMutableArray *linksArray; // Assume that this contains objects which respond to the -taskOne method

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"taskOne" ascending:YES];
[linksArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` returns a new array; it does not sort in-place. If you want to sort in-place, use `sortUsingDescriptors:`.

Comment: @TomaszSzulc Sorry, I missed the bit about it being a mutable array. I've added a second example which shows how to use an `NSSortDescriptor` to do an in-place sort.

Answer (score 1):

this looks like a kind of bubblesort, but you need two loops. currently you run one time through your array and the highest object should be at the latest index. Now you need to run through the array until length-1. try something like this:

```
for (Byte j = 1; j < [linksArray count]; j++) {
    for (Byte i = 0; i < [linksArray count]-j; i++) {
        //your code from above
    }
}
```